# How come I can't see different folders other than Java folders in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded AndroidStudio. It is my 1st day of using it.

I imported my project files that I used to open in Eclipse. And when I expand the file structure, I can't see the manifest files or my other folders.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And when I expand the file structure

That's not the file structure. You'll probably be more comfortable if you switch the "Android" drop-down above the "file structure" tree to "Project". This will give you more of an Eclipse-style, "this is what's on the filesystem" view of your project.

Comment: you are awesome - I remember some years ago you used to help me A LOT :) Thank you again. Your suggestion worked.